# How can I iterate through JSON properties and assign those values to elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have looked up several questions/answers that are doing something similar to what I want to do, but I haven't found anything quite right yet.

I'm fairly new to JSON, so any help is appreciated.

I have the following JSON returned from a Web API controller in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "ABCDE Shipping",
    "AddressL1": "1234 ABC Lane",
    "AddressL2": null
}
```

Each of those properties in the JSON object corresponds to a field in a form. I want to iterate through those properties and assign the values to the fields in the form. For example, `AddressL1` would go in the AddressL1 field. Here is what I have tried:

```
$("#ipt_shipperSearch").blur(function () {
        //ajax api test on blur
        $.ajax({
            url: "theApiController",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var shipperFields = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control shipper");
                if ($("#ipt_shipperSearch").val() != null && $("#ipt_shipperSearch").val() != "") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < shipperFields.length; i++) {
                        shipperFields[i].value = data.Name;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.toString());
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I have an array of the form fields to which I want to assign the above JSON properties called `shipperFields`. I have it so that the name is assigned to all of the fields, but this is obviously not the result I want. How can I iterate through the JSON object's properties and assign those values to the fields in question? I was thinking something like `data[i]`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` will return an array of the keys in an object.  You can loop over that to do whatever you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "Name": "ABCDE Shipping",
  "AddressL1": "1234 ABC Lane",
  "AddressL2": null
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (fieldName, index) {
  if (data[fieldName]) {
    document.querySelector(`input[name="${fieldName}"]`).value = data[fieldName];
    document.getElementById(fieldName).value = data[fieldName];
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.form-control.shipper')[index].value = data[fieldName];
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="text" name="Name">
  <input type="text" name="AddressL1">
  <input type="text" name="AddressL2">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="id">
  <input type="text" id="Name">
  <input type="text" id="AddressL1">
  <input type="text" id="AddressL2">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control shipper">
  <input type="text" class="form-control shipper">
  <input type="text" class="form-control shipper">
  <input type="text" class="form-control shipper">
</div>
```

I've added a version that uses positional logic, which I would greatly suggest you not choose to use as it will be brittle.  And I also changed the `=>` to be a normal function if you are not ES6 compatible.

Comment: For the record, I didn't down vote this. I like this approach a lot. I suppose this approach requires you to have the `Name` attribute set for your inputs, right?

Comment: Yes, but if you had ids that corresponded to the keys, you could find them that way too.  Do you want an id version?

Comment: @Actually, I'd like to see a class name version. My class name is `form-control shipper`. Is this possible?

Comment: How does the object keys relate to the class names? are there like `class="AddressL1"` inside the from-control shipper element?

Comment: Well, right now, I have it like this: `var shipperFields = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control shipper");` This array has all of the fields I'm worried about. They are also in the correct order already, so all I need to is something like this: `shipperFields[i] = data[i];` Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot guarantee "order" on an object's keys.  If you can find the element by a name/class/id it is much more preferred.

Comment: Okay I will add the names. By the way, I copied your answer directly, and it wouldn't run because it detected a syntax error. It doesn't like the arrow. `=>`

Comment: I got rid of the `=>` since your error suggests you are not ES6 compatible and added a positional example.

Comment: I'm just getting around to fixing this. Thanks for the answer. Would you happen to know why I'm getting a syntax error on this line: `document.querySelector(`input[name="${fieldName}"]`).value = data[fieldName];`

Comment: `document.querySelector()` expects a string as an argument.  You are giving it a string not surrounded by single/double quotes or the string literal character.

Comment: Oh, I noticed that you're using the back tick character "`" in your example. Is that legal syntax?

Comment: Yes, the back tick is the template literal character (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  It allows you to construct strings dynamically without appending.

Comment: Okay thank you. I must still be doing something wrong. I'm still getting a syntax error when I use the back tick. I'm reading up on it now.